# pybind11 data type isn't matched for map, as an input argument for function

Tags: pybind11

Data type:

`std::map<platform::String, platform::String> ssmap;`

Binding code:

dt.cpp (-> import dt)

```
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/stl_bind.h>
#include "./ssmap.h"

PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::map<platform::String, platform::String>>)

void bind_string(py::module &m)
{
py::classplatform::String pyClass(m, "String);
pyClass.def(py::init<const std::String&>(), py::return_value_policy::move);
...
}
void bind_ssmap(py::module &m)
{
py::bind_map<platform::String, platform::String>>(m, "ssmap");
}
...
```

Then in another module, I'll use ssmap:
vp.cpp (import vp)

```
void bind_vp(py::module &m)
{
py::class pyClass(m, "vp", py::module_local());
pyClass.def("reset", &vp::reset, py::arg("val")); ---> val is type of ssmap
}
```

// test script:

```
import dt
import vp

val = dt.ssmap()
print("type of val is ", type(val))

str = dt.string("Hi")
val[str]=str

vp.reset(val) --> gave error
```

Errors: TypeError: reset(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:

1. (self: vp, value: Dict[std::String, std::String]) -> None

If I checked the type of val, it shows:
type of val is : <class 'dt.ssmap'>

So why the input argument (val) is taken as Dict, but the ssmap is taken as class of ssmap (but not Dict), What is the right way to deal with this case?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::map<platform::String, platform::String>>)` in `vp.cpp` as well, or at least in a common header. Otherwise when you bind `reset` the bindings will not be aware that this type is opaque.